# How to disable print manipulation in Stack Overflow CVs?

Tags: support, cv-export

Whenever I was trying to print the CV page it comes as a FORMAL textual pdf.

Why can't we make the CV page also be printed like any other HTML page?

Comment: What's wrong with the PDF form?

Comment: @Makoto There is hell lot of wrong because as a user I literally hate the way it comes now in the PDF. I wanted it to be printed as any other page

Comment: That doesn't really answer Makoto's question. Exactly what makes you "hate the way it comes now in the PDF"?

Comment: @duplode I wanted to print my CV page as any other NORMAL HTML pages, I wanted that page to look same in PDF as it looks in my browser

Comment: Wait a minute.  Are you clicking on either view (story or traditional) and selecting Print, or are you saving it as a PDF first?  I will absolutely admit that either view and trying to print it out looks horrible.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I wanted to print my CV page as any other NORMAL HTML pages, I wanted that page to look same in PDF as it looks in my browser

Comment: Okay.  That *might* be a bug.  If you save your PDF and try to print that, how does it look?  Look for the "Save as PDF" button on the main Dev Story page.

Comment: @Makoto It doesn't print as any other HTML page, it prints as an ugly PDF

Comment: Let me be sure I've got this *clear*.  On the Developer Story, if you hit "Save as PDF", you download a PDF to your computer.  How does this PDF look?  Alternatively, if you select either "Story View" or "Traditional View" and try to print it, how does it look?  I have a hunch that you're running into an inconsistency with that system, which would turn this into a bug report of sorts, but I want to be sure that there's a bug rather than an opinion.

Comment: @Makoto It comes as a plain text, [this CV](http://stackoverflow.com/cv/xameeramir) when printed looks very ugly. It not even adds my photo in the PDF

Comment: [It is "Stack Overflow", not "Stackoverflow "](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (the last section, "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name"). Please edit your question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I see what's going on here, and I think it's a bug.  I'll repost this as a bug a bit later.

The long and short of it:  the print style for non-Developer Story CVs is broken.

On the top is what my Developer Story CV looks like, and on the bottom is *any other* format.  Note that this contains freely volunteered information, and the information I **don't** want to volunteer is blurred.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So by when can this bug be solved?